# Received validation error from SOAP API

Tags: soap-api, marketing-cloud, .net

When I am testing TriggeredSend Functionality in the APIStarterKit project (with SOAP API and .NET), I got below error response from exacttarget after Update is called.

How do I know what are those 4 validations errors ? Code may wrong. I am still not sure how to find what are those errors as I am new to ExactTarget.

UpdateResult[] uResults = client.Update(new UpdateOptions(), new APIObject[] { tsd }, out uRequestID, out uStatus);

Status Message: The email ID=31085257, contained 4 validation errors. Refer to the Triggered Send Email Validation error log

Appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: Hi Randy - make sure that if the answers you get solve your issue, to toggle the check mark near the answer to green.  This is your privilege as the asker, and only you can do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to go to the actual email you are using for your TriggeredSend by navigating to the Content tab in the Marketing Cloud.

Then check the checkbox next to your email and click Validate in the toolbar at the top - After selecting your target audience you'll be shown the errors that are in your email.