# Programmatically access error log

Tags: marketing-cloud, validation, email-validation

Can the error log from Salesforce Marketing Cloud be accessed via API calls (either REST or SOAP), using an error log ID?

For example, this is the status message I got from making an `Update` on a `TriggeredSendDefinition`.

```
<StatusMessage>The email ID=25860, contained 1 validation errors. Refer to the Triggered Send Email Validation error log, ID = 1626068765</StatusMessage>
```

This is relevant to [this other posted question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/27371/received-validation-error-from-soap-api), but I'm curious if there's a programmatic way to retrieve what the errors are.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a shame, but as of now only the Journey Builder Audit Log  is accessible programmatically: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/getInteractionAuditLog.htm

Here's an idea that you can upvote to make error logs accessible for users: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000E1wOAAS.

Currently, you can only troubleshoot the validation error you are facing by going to Email Studio > Content Builder and performing a Send Preview for the email used in Triggered Send: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_perform_subscriber_preview_test_send.htm&type=5